# Trace norm differentiation with respect to a column

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning, matrix-rank

I want to know if is it possible to get a derivative or an approximation of the derivative of the trace norm with respect to a column. More specifically if we have a matrix containing in each of its elements a function of a parameter 'w', how to get the derivative of the trace norm of this matrix with respect to 'w'?

Comment: Well, how would you use the chain rule in this context? 
I know that the derivative of the trace norm with respect to the concerned matrix is UV' where U and V come from the svd decomposition (supposing that the singular values are all positives) but i want something different. I want the derivative with respect to a parameter present in the elements of the matrix.

Comment: What's the dependence of the matrix elements on the parameter?  Can you apply the chain rule?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. You mind want to expand your question with more details of your work.